# tfs builder: the process template could not be loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm trying to open an existing process template in visual studio tfs,

but get the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

**Update**
these are my Build Controller's properties:

[image]

these are one of his Agents' properties:

[image]

Comment: has the template been customised at all?

Comment: can you check your build server config - in visual studio right click the build node, click manage build controllers, then properties on your build controller. Is there anything in your "version control path to custom assemblies" ?

Comment: Right, so the TFSCustomActivitiesDLLs folder contains some DLL's you need loaded to open the workflow.  The way you normally fix this is create a new VS project, reference all the DLLs in that directory and add the build template to the project.  Then open the template with the project open.  Here's a guide - http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20extensions%20into%20a%20build%20template&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @Betty where is my TFSCustomActivitiesDLLs  ?

Comment: see your screenshot - $/TFSBuilds/TFSBuildCustomisations/TFSCustomActivitiesDLLS  it actually appears that whomever setup your TFS server structured it fairly well, you may find there's already a solution/project for doing customisations in $/TFSBuilds/TFSBuildCustomisations/